# Windows Server 2019 GPO - "User Policy Update Failed"

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2019, update, failed

My clients environment is a mix of **Windows 2012, 2016 and 2019 servers**. Recently we had a few additional Windows 2019 servers provisioned and added to our domain. When I run `gpupdate /force` from the command line on these newly provisioned 2019 instances I get the following error - "***User Policy Update Failed***".

If I run `gpresult /h gpo.html` and review the results in a browser its showing "**No Errors Detected**" under the "last user profile" refresh section at the top of the Group Policy Results page. Scrolling down the page I don't see any errors either. If I run the `gpupdate /force` command on ***existing*** 2019 instances the user policy updates **do not fail**.

Any idea why I'm getting different results with the **Group Policy Results html page** vs. the **gpupdate /force** command? The VM instances are provisioned by an IT team so I have no control on the image used. It looks like some additional local security policies were put in place with these new instances. Is it possible the local policies are conflicting with the user policy updates?

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look in the "System", and "Application" event log, and "Applications and services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Group Policy -> Operational", see if you can find interesting things there.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I checked these logs and didn't see any useful errors/warning reported. Any other thoughts?